# Spring Boot 2 upgrade. permit All works with .anonymous().and() .. but why?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I had migrated Oauth2 code from Spring Boot 1.3.2 T Spring Boot 2.0.2.

The below code to permit "/auth" endpoint is not working in springBoot 2

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity                
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

    }
```

/auth endpoint return 401 response.

After research I hadd added

**.anonymous().and()**

and it working as expected now. /auth return result with out token.

I am not able to figure out the reason, what changed in spring boot 2. ?

Comment: refer to this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity `The default configuration above:`
`Ensures that any request to our application requires the user to be authenticated`